# Why are my values in my array turning into 0's after a certain length in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, type-conversion

```
const digits = [5,2,2,6,5,7,1,9,0,3,8,6,8,6,5,2,1,8,7,9,8];

var plusOne = function(digits) {
  var value;
  var numbers;
  value = digits.join('');
  value = Number(value);
  value += 1;
  numbers = Array.from(String(value), Number);
  return numbers;
};

console.log(plusOne(digits)); // Output => [5,2,2,6,5,7,1,9,0,3,8,6,8,6,5,2,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Instead, I would like it to output [5,2,2,6,5,7,1,9,0,3,8,6,8,6,5,2,1,8,7,9,9]. Here is the exact question being asked from LeetCode.

https://leetcode.com/problems/plus-one/

I would also like to mention that if `digits.length > 21` the output would be:

[
5, NaN, 2,   2,   6, 5, 7,
1,   9, 0,   3,   8, 6, 8,
6,   5, 2, NaN, NaN, 2, 1
]

Why are these happening?

Comment: I suggest you add `console.log(String(value))` to see what it is you are trying to convert to an array of digits. *"Why are these happening?"* JavaScript can only represent integers without loss of precision up to 53 bits. (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`). If you want to work with arbitrarily large integers you'd have to use a library that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement plusOne. Your idea failed because there is a limit to size of integers in JavaScript. See comments above.
To solve lets go from right to left, summing like humans do.
Another option is to use a library for this, such as [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) or even browser's native [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) which I haven't looked into.

```js
var digits = [5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 7, 1, 9, 0, 3, 8, 6, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1, 8, 7, 9, 9]

console.log("" + digits)
console.log("" + plusOne(digits))

function plusOne(digits) {
  var result = [];
  var carry = 1

  while (digits.length) {
    var digit = digits.pop();
    digit += carry;
    if (digit > 9) {
      digit = digit - 10;
      carry = 1;
    } else {
      carry = 0;
    }
    result.push(digit);
  }
  if (carry) {
    result.push(carry)
  }
  return result.reverse();
}
```

Comment: You might want to also address the OP's question: *Why are these happening?*

Comment: You did that already on your comment. I will add a reference

Comment: Fair enough :) ...

Comment: I am just slightly confused about pushing `carry` in `result`. When I console.log carry in the block of code, nothing comes out. What does it do?

Comment: Also, how did you get the 7 and the 9 at the end of the array to increment as well when you add one to the array? Wouldn't the `digit` be stuck at 0 because of the first time it went through the if statement?

Comment: I keep popping digits from the right side, adding carry=1 or carry=0. It is usually 0 except the first one, unless the sum is bigger than 9, then we have a carry=1 for the next digit.